# Reading json values after loading to a store

Tags: extjs4

I am trying to read the values from json which is returned from the db. But I am unable to do that. Its giving undefined. 
In Firebug its giving the correct values in the following format
    { "COLUMNS":["B","C","D","E","F","G"],
      "DATA":[[1.253,0.54,2.54,8.245,0,0.253]]
    }

When I give console.log(response[0].DATA.B), its giving undefined.
I tried alert(response[0].get('B')); This is also giving undefined.
alert(success) is giving true.

Can someone please tell me what is going wrong here.

Thanks in advance..
Here is the code I am using

```
Ext.define('DBRec', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [
{name:'A', type :'string'},
{name:'B', type:'string'},
{name:'C', type:'string'},
{name:'D', type:'string'},
{name:'E', type:'string'},
{name:'F', type:'string'},
{name:'G', type:'string'}
]
});

var DBRecStore=Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
model: 'DBRec',
proxy: {
type: 'ajax',
url : 'dbFunctions.cfc?method=getRec',
reader: {
    type:'json',
    root:'DATA',
    fields: ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'] 
    } 
}
});

function loadLimits()
{
  DBRecStore.load({
  params: {
    reader: 'json',
    returnFormat: 'JSON'
  },
 callback: function(response, options, success){
    alert(DBRecStore.getCount());
    if (DBRecStore.getCount() == '0') {
       alert("no records found");

    }
   else
   {
       alert("records found");
       console.log(response[0].DATA.B+" "+response[0].DATA.C);
   }
 }
 });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you not using your own reader, as i see you don't, then your **data** array must be a objects array, not array of arrays.

`{ "DATA":[{a:1.253,b: 0.54,c: 2.54,d:8.245,e:0,0.253}] }`

And you don't need to define field in store, it's already in model.

Comment: Prodigy..So how will I get the values of that array?

Comment: If you don't want to change your incoming data - make your reader. You can extend: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Json

Comment: I cannot vhange the server response. I tried to give reader: { type:'json', root:'COLUMNS', record:'DATA',fields: ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'] } But still its not alerting the value from db.

Comment: I created my own reader, but its giving TypeError: d is undefined But in firebug, still its giving the response..Not sure whats the problem                                                        proxy: { type: 'ajax', url : 'dbFunctions.cfc?method=getRec', reader : new Ext.data.JsonReader({ root : 'COLUMNS', record : 'DATA' }), fields: ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'] }